# How to find syntax error at PID segment in ANSI X12 for EDI 810

Tags: edi

I am new to SPS commerce I have multiple invoice errors. I have error message but not able to identify how to fix it and where to fix it as the system showing error message but don't know where exactly. I am attaching error message please any one help me on this.

Element PID05 (Description) contains characters not listed in the allowed character set. Segment PID is defined in the guideline at position 060.

This error was detected at:
Segment Count: 37
Element Count: 5
Characters: 12304 through 12349

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any special characters like *, ~ or > in your Product descriptions?

Answer (score 1):

PID05 contains the Item description details and it might contain the special char that you configured in EDI agreement as a separator. Kindly check if have any special char or separator listed there, then remove it and process.